# Disable gesture recognizer of background views

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have some small views added as subviews of a single view. Some of these small views respond to the double tap.

In some circumstances one of this view may be zoomed in and it covers most of the others view.

The zoomed view may be zoomed out by the means of a double tap.

The problem is that the double tap used to zoom out the view is also received by the background views which react to it.

How can I avoid the double tap propagation to the background views without disabling the recognizers of each view one by one ?

Thank you

Comment: try the canceltouchesinview property and set it to yes.This may help you.